# apache poi upgrade from 2.5 to 3.8 gives Excel error

Tags: java, apache-poi, excel-2010

We need to provide support for Excel 2010 so have upgraded to Apache poi 3.8. But while downloading the excel it takes so much time for opening and also provides error message as
 "EXCEL found unreadable content. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this workbook, click yes"

And after clicking "yes", it gives me one more pop up which says,

Excel completed file level validation and repair. Some parts of this workbook may have been repaired or discarded.
Removed Records: Merge cells from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part

Kindly help me resolving this issue.

Thank-you

Comment: Does this happen for all files, or just very complex ones? Can you identify what part of the file is causing the issue? And how come you're not using the latest version of POI (3.9)?

Comment: its happening with all the files and it takes about 10 mins to open a file.

Comment: What about just creating a very simple file, does a very simple one open without error?

Comment: have a look http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/excel-found-unreadable-content-in-xls-do-you-want/5bc64db0-e4d6-44d8-9409-c6035da6033e

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem using POI 3.9

It was the following

1. I created the XLSX spreadsheet in ***LibreOffice*** 4.0.2.2
2. I could open this ***LibreOffice*** generated XLSX in Office 2010 with no
   problems
3. With POI I opened this workbook and wrote to it. Very simple stuff,
   Strings only
4. Office 2010 then reports that my XLSX is corrupt and 'fixes' it

I created a new XLSX in Word 2010 and modified it with POI 3.9 and the problem went away

Answer (score 0):

I had a exact problem using POI 4.0.0

The issue is with POI version. I downgrade the version from 4.0.0 to 3.17 and the problem resolved.

Comment: I am creating excel using Java. I was getting error message "EXCEL found unreadable content. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this workbook, click yes" when I try to open Excel in **Microsoft Excel** which has no issues if I open same file in **LibreOffice**. I am using POI jar version 4.0.0 which is actually causing the issue. Now I am using POI 3.17 which has resolved the issue.