# Java - Appending data to same Excel file with FileOutputStream

Tags: java

I am trying to write data on excel file. But each time I execute the program new file gets created with new data I even tried `FileOutputStream(File file, true)`, but excel file throws **error**

> "Excel completed file level validation and repair. Some parts of this
>   workbook may have been repaired or discarded."

Below is the code I am trying . Thank you in advance .

```
class ExcelDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Employee Data1");

    Map<String, Object[]> data = new TreeMap<String, Object[]>();

    Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();
    int rownum = 0;       
      data.put("1", new Object[]{"ID", "NAME", "LASTNAME", "AGE"});
      data.put("2", new Object[]{1, "Amit", "Shukla", "12"});
      data.put("3", new Object[]{2, "Lokesh", "Gupta", "13"});
      data.put("4", new Object[]{3, "John", "Adwards", "14"});
      data.put("5", new Object[]{4, "Brian", "Schultz", "15"});
      data.put("6", new Object[]{5, "Amit", "Shukla", "12"});

    for (String key : keyset) {
        Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
        Object[] objArr = data.get(key);
        int cellnum = 0;
        for (Object obj : objArr) {
            Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
            if (obj instanceof String) {
                cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
            } else if (obj instanceof Integer) {
                cell.setCellValue((Integer) obj);
            }
        }
    }
    try {
        //Write the workbook in file system
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("G:\\demo.xlsx", true);           
        workbook.write(out);            
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        System.out.println("demo.xlsx written successfully on disk.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: based on what I understand from google, your file must be corrupted. can you delete the file manually and run the code to see if you get the same error?

Comment: Yes I deleted the file manually stil I am getting the same error -

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292939/apache-poi-upgrade-from-2-5-to-3-8-gives-excel-error

Comment: some pages say this is very uncommon issue lol lucky u

Comment: have you added following jars : **1. `dom4j-1.6.1.jar` 2. `poi-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar` 3. `poi-ooxml-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar` 4. `poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10-FINAL.jar` 5. `xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar`**

Comment: lol thank you so much for taking your time @Kick Buttowski

Comment: @ atish shimpi -  I am using poi 3.9, dom4j-1.6.1.jar, poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar, poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203.jar, xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar

Comment: why are you appending to the file anyway? It makes no sense to me

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below code it worked

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("G:\\demo.xlsx", true)
```

it should be written as

```
File yourFile = new File("G:\\demo.xlsx");           
  if (!yourFile.exists()) {
           yourFile.createNewFile();
                  }
          FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(yourFile, false);
          workbook.write(out);
```