# Can we append two excel sheets in java?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to append the existing Excel sheet's data with new data it is possible using the reference code from [Java - Appending data to same Excel file with FileOutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27010800/java-appending-data-to-same-excel-file-with-fileoutputstream) (this is the link from which I took the reference).

Is there any other approach to append the entire Excel sheet directly to an existing Excel sheet without overriding the current data in the existing Excel sheet?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
// Create an POI Workbook from your FileInput:
try (InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("c:\\path\\to\\your\\file.xlsx")); 
    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(in);
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("c:\\path\\to\\your\\newfile.xlsx")) {

    // get the first sheet
    Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    // get the last row in the sheet
    int lastRowNum = firstSheet.getLastRowNum()

    // add data after the lastRow
    Row newRow = firstSheet.createRow(lastRowNum + 1);
    Cell newCell = newRow.createCell(0);
    newCell.setCellValue("newData");

    // and finally write the file somewhere
    workbook.write(out);
}
```